# Put value from javascript combo box

Tags: javascript

I want to get the value from a combo box in javascript.

This is the combo box code:

```
<select name="no_kk" style="width: 68%;" class="select2" id="no_kk" onchange="get_Nokk(this.value);" >
    <option value="">-- Pilih Nomor KK --</option>
    <?php
        $kk = get_no_kk();

        foreach ($kk as $key => $value) {?>
            <option value="<?php echo $value->no_kk;?>"><?php echo $value->no_kk;?></option>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    </option>
</select>
```

I want to put the value I choose in this code here:

```
<div class="right">
     <a href="javascript:FormRegIdv(\''<?php echo $amil['email'];?>'\',\''**.........here.........**'\');" class="button-submit-blue" style="width:40px; height:55px;">TAMBAH</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to set `select` a value ?

Comment: the condition is.. when i choose combo box.. get value .. then .. the value put on here FormRegIdv(\''<?php echo $amil['email'];?>'\',\''**.........here.........**'\') .. put on text **"here"** may you know ? @passion

Comment: Not able to understand what you want ...

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a problem. Is better for you to leave the `href` empty and then replace it using JS. I let you an example:

```js
function calculateURL(option){
 return a + option;
}

(function() {
console.log(document.querySelector(".button-submit-blue").href)

document.querySelector("#mySelect").addEventListener("change", function(evt){
 var option = document.querySelector("#mySelect").value;
  document.querySelector(".button-submit-blue").href = calculateURL(option);
  alert("The value selected is: "+document.querySelector("#mySelect").value);
  alert("The new link is: " + document.querySelector(".button-submit-blue").href)
}, false); 

})();
```

```html
<script>
var a = "http://www."; //this represents values grab from PHP
</script>


<select id="mySelect">
<option value="">--</option>
<option value="google.com">google</option>
<option value="yahoo.com">yahoo</option>
</select>

<div class="right">
     <a href="#" class="button-submit-blue" style="width:40px; height:55px;">TAMBAH</a>
</div>
```

This is easy. First of all you need to set a listener for the change event on your `select`. This is set using `addEventListener` function. This function has several arguments, the first is the event you want to listen, `change`, the second is the callback, which will be executed everytime the event change is fired. Finally, you only have to take the selected `option` and recalculate your url.